# How can I join 2 tables with different time formats?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I have the following Command:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("", Connection);

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + Felder + " 
               FROM QS.KO10 LEFT OUTER JOIN QS.FB56 
               ON (KO1007 = FB5601) " + Where;
```

But this `commandtext` does not work because it's not enough to connect `KO1007 = FB5601`. I have to connect the Datetimes `KO1025 and FB5605`too, but the problem is they are in different formats. I would need `KO1025 = FB5605`, but `KO1025` is YYYYMM and `FB5605` is YYMMDD. How do I join these two tables?

`KO1007 and FB5601` are just numbers for orders, but these numbers can be more than one time in the datatable, therefore I need to also connect with the two datetime columns to have the exact order.

Comment: What DB are you using?  Are these fields strings or numerics?

Comment: Use functions to extract `YYYYMM` from `FB5605`. It might be something like this `SUBSTR(KO1025, 3, 4) = SUBSTR(FB5605, 1, 4)`

Comment: Both numerics, and it's DB/2

Comment: Also, as much as `KO1025` and `FB5605` might be meaningful names to you, they don't tell a lot to someone not working with you. Any chance you could specify your table schema, at least the relevant columns?

Comment: They are just Datetimes, i don't know what to say more... i'll write some more information in the question one sec...

Comment: Could you multiply that YYYYMM column by 100 and add 01 (to get to YYYYMM01) and add 20000000 to that YYMMDD to end up with 20YYMMDD? Supposing of course that all those years are in this century.

Comment: @HansKesting can you maybe write that out how i would add it in my command? i'm sorry but i have no idea how to do this but at least it sounds logic...

Comment: @Lolo i tried that and it seems to work... i will continue testing and post an answer when i got it

Comment: What is the data type of KO1025 and FB5605 in database? Are they varchar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lolo's comment was good i did it like this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN QS.FB56 ON (KO1007 = FB5601 AND SUBSTR(KO1025, 3, 4) = SUBSTR(FB5605, 1, 4)
```